# How Can I Send Text (and Not a Text File) to My Printer on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, printing

I know about this question ([How do I send ASCII text to printer (over USB)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93881/how-do-i-send-ascii-text-to-printer-over-usb)).  But I'm working on something different.  I'd like to be able to send text from within a bash script or Perl script to my printer.

Everything I find tells me about sending a text file to my printer.  Is there any way to send text from within a script?  (That way I don't have to generate the text, save it as a file, then print the file, then delete the file.)

Comment: What printer are you using ??

Comment: Generically, to any printer.  Most of the time I'm using a Brother HL 1440.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lp` is able to read data from standard input, see `man lp`:

> lp  submits  files for printing or alters a pending job. Use a filename of "-" to force printing from the standard input.

So if you followed the advice given in the referenced question to install a "raw" printer you should be able to run

```
echo "whatever text you want to print" | lp -d Generic_usbtb -
```

Comment: That works, but with a glitch.  Do you know how I'd specify a line feed or carriage return?  I tried "\n" as well as "\r" and they come through literally.

Comment: Found it.  Use "echo -e" to enable escaped characters and with that "\n" gives me a linefeed and carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about RAW printing.

> What is Raw Printing?
>
> "Raw Printing", "DOS Printing", "Line Mode Printing", or generically
>   any "Page Description Language (PDL)", are all examples of sending a
>   series of characters directly to the printer in the printer's native
>   language. This is the recommended approach when using jZebra because
>   jZebra is able to bypasses the default print behavior of your web
>   browser and allows you to "program" your own print commands.

[How to Raw printing on OSX 10.8](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialRawOSX)

Read the nice and clean instructions how to set it up:

[image]

Comment: That's some good information, but it's a lot of work, kind of like going around your thumb to get to your elbow.